# SVN permission error attempting to commit

Tags: svn, permissions, aix

We've upgraded our AIX 7.1 to 7.2, in the process we upgraded the existing Subversion from 1.8 to 1.10.6. We use svnserve for access to the various repositories on the server which is run locally owned by a non-root userid.

Since the upgrade while users can check out code they can no longer commit to any of the repositories, getting the error:

`svn: E000013: Can't open file '../repositories/repo1/db/revs/102/102015': The file access permissions do not allow the specified action.`

The db file in question is created by the commit process & as far back as I can see the files have always been created without write permissions:

`svnserver:/svn/repositories/repo1/db/revs/102>$ ll -t | head total 1072 -r--r--r-- 1 svnadmin svnadmin    887 Dec  8 12:38 102015 -r--r--r-- 1 svnadmin svnadmin  14878 Dec  2 15:52 102014 -r--r--r-- 1 svnadmin svnadmin  15128 Dec  2 14:26 102013 -r--r--r-- 1 svnadmin svnadmin   5749 Dec  2 12:40 102012 -r--r--r-- 1 svnadmin svnadmin   5795 Dec  2 12:37 102011 -r--r--r-- 1 svnadmin svnadmin 115480 Dec  1 11:13 102010 -r--r--r-- 1 svnadmin svnadmin 115571 Dec  1 11:02 102009 -r--r--r-- 1 svnadmin svnadmin 113681 Dec  1 10:52 102008 -r--r--r-- 1 svnadmin svnadmin 116811 Dec  1 10:46 102007`

None of my google hits have brought me close to a solution, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe the disk partition became somehow read‐only and the file-permissions only mirror this? Anyways, `chmod 0644` should be tried.

Answer (score 0):

For the record downgrading from SVN 1.10.6 to 1.9.3 resolved the issue.